# Process viewer for Win CE devices

Tags: windows-ce

i have to find out a memory leak issue on windows ce 4.0/5.0 device. Is there any tool which shows me the all the processes info, like memory, handle count... So that i can identify the culprit process.

If there are any memory leak detection tools for CE 4.0/5.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.vttoth.com/LPK/taskmanager.html

This is kind of old, but might still work.

Answer (score 3):

The best tool, by a very long margin, for this is [Entrek's CodeSnitch](http://entrek.com/codesnitch.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/MobileTaskManager.aspx). Provided that the Toolhelp32 library is available in your device, you could easily write code that enumerates processes and memory.

Answer (score 0):

[acbTaskMan](http://www.acbpocketsoft.com/Products/acbTaskMan/acbTaskMan-Overview-7.html) works like a charm for me. The free version does not show per-process information, but paid version is not too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

How about [PocketPC Process Explorer](http://madebits.com/tools/pocketpc-process-explorer.php) - it's free and offers several cool features.

Answer (score 0):

This one is free and works like a charm: [ITaskMgr](http://urana.info/mobile/wince/itaskmgr/index.html)